# Disable Open Session In View vs handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_STATEMENT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

## Problem

There are "database connection" issue with large monolith Spring Boot application I'm working on which all boils down to the fact that the app is not releasing DB connection back to the pool.

Consider the following scenario: a service method that is called from the controller:

```java
void myMethod() {
  userRepository.findById(userId);
  thread.sleep(4000); // simulate remote method call
  userFriendsRepository.getFriendsByUserId(userId);
  thread.sleep(4000); // simulate remote method call
}
```

application.properties

```
# Throw a warning when connection is not released
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=3000
```

We're trying to evaluate the potential solutions:

## Potential solutions

1. After research there is one obvious solution to this problem is to **disable open-session** in view pattern (since the Spring holds the hibernate session during the entire duration of the http request):

   ```
   spring.jpa.open-in-view = false
   ```

   In this case Side effects have to do with entity relationships.
2. Disabling auto-commit and setting hibernate connection setting to release after statement:

   ```
   spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.handling_mode=
   DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_STATEMENT
   ```

   This approach is less clear.

## Questions:

The main questions I have:

- Why using approach number #2 warning `Apparent connection leak detected` is still shown, even though the property says "release connection after statement". My understanding is that "statement" in this context is a SQL query and should be release right after the method `userRepository.findById(userId);` and before `thread.sleep(4000);` is even started. Please note, here I'm taking about just #2, "open-in-view" is still enabled.

  Interesting observation: Using #2 and decreasing `thread.sleep` to `2000`, `Apparent connection leak detected` is not shown anymore. Even though both timeouts combined exceed "leak threshold". It seems like the connection is released right before executing the next query and not the right after it has finished the prev one (even with open-session-in-view turned on).
- In #2, does disabling auto-commit can affect the application? I see Spring already disables auto-commit in each transaction:

  ```java
  public class DataSourceTransactionManager {
     protected void doBegin(...) {
       ...
       con.setAutoCommit(false);
       ...
     }
  }
  ```

  According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750087/pros-and-cons-of-changing-autocommit-true-in-spring-boot-application#comment84527257_48750087), it shouldn't, but I'm wondering why it's on in Spring by default then. Is it because of the backwards compatibility?
- Have you faced something similar db connection issues in your project and how did you go about it?

I'm personally inclined toward the #1 approach, disabling open-session-in-view, but I want to understand these 2 approaches before making a decision and which impact they're going to make on existing application.

P.s. Vlad Mihalcea has an [excellent article on this topic](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-transaction-connection-management/?unapproved=161049&moderation-hash=50511716b401e87705fe672010e1370b#comment-161049), but it doesn't compare the 2 approaches and answer my specific questions (or maybe I didn't understand the article 100%).

Comment: Where are the transactional boundaries in your example?

Comment: No transactions in my code, those are just read operations. However, I know, by default, spring almost always wraps all operations (even reads) into transactions.

Comment: @skryvets did I understand properly that the Q is actually not about connection leaks, but about time application holds JDBC connection w/o using it?

Comment: The original q - why database connection is not closed after each statement in Spring. Part of the answer I found, the other part I found I don’t understand 100%.

Comment: You should definitely not to set `handling_mode` to `DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_STATEMENT`, that is clearly stated in [Hibernate javadocs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.9.Final/org/hibernate/ConnectionReleaseMode.html#AFTER_STATEMENT): Indicates that JDBC connection should be aggressively released after each SQL statement is executed. In this mode, the application must explicitly close all iterators and scrollable results. **This mode may only be used with a JTA datasource.** Why you do not observe any effect - plz take advantage of using debugger.